# Get Non-Static MethodInfo for IEnumerable<T>.First() (Or make the static method work with EF)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression-trees

I have a method, `GetSearchExpression`, defined as:

```
    private Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetSearchExpression(
        string targetField, ExpressionType comparison, object value, IEnumerable<EnumerableResultQualifier> qualifiers = null);
```

At a high level, the method takes in a Field or Property (such as `Order.Customer.Name`), a comparison type (like `Expression.Equals`), and a value (like "Billy"), then returns a lambda expression suitable for input to a `Where` statement `o => o.Customer.Name == "Billy"}`.

Recently, I discovered an issue. Sometimes, the field I need is actually the field of an item in a collection (like `Order.StatusLogs.First().CreatedDate`).

I *feel* like that should be easy. The code that creates the left side of the expression (above, `o => o.Customer.Name`) is as follows:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
Expression left = null;
//turn "Order.Customer.Name" into List<string> { "Customer", "Name" }
var deQualifiedFieldName = DeQualifyFieldName(targetField, typeof(T));

//loop through each part and grab the specified field or property
foreach (var part in deQualifiedFieldName)
    left = Expression.PropertyOrField(left == null ? param : left, part);
```

It *seems* like I should be able to revise this to check if the field/property exists, and if not, try to call a method by that name instead. It would look like this:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
Expression left = null;
var deQualifiedFieldName = DeQualifyFieldName(targetField, typeof(T));
var currentType = typeof(T);
foreach (var part in deQualifiedFieldName)
{
    //this gets the Type of the current "level" we're at in the hierarchy passed via TargetField
    currentType = SingleLevelFieldType(currentType, part);
    if (currentType != null) //if the field/property was found
    {
        left = Expression.PropertyOrField(left == null ? param : left, part);                    
    }
    else
    {   //if the field or property WASN'T found, it might be a method                    
        var method = currentType.GetMethod(part, Type.EmptyTypes); //doesn't accept parameters
        left = Expression.Call(left, method);
        currentType = method.ReturnType;
    }                
}
```

The problem is that statement near the end (`var method currentType.GetMethod(part, Type.EmptyTypes);`).  Turns out "First" and "Last" don't exist for `IEnumerable` objects, so I get a null exception when I try to use my Method object. In fact, the only way I can EVER them to show up in a `GetMethod()` call is by calling `typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod()`. That's useless of course, because then I get a static method in return rather than the instance method I need.

As a side-note: I tried using the static method, but Entity Framework throws a fit and won't accept it as part of the lambda.

I need help getting the instance `MethodInfo` of `IEnumerable.First()` & `Last()`. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Marc and Ivan for their input. They deserve credit as without their help I would have spent much longer finding a solution. However, as neither answer solved the issue I was having, I'm posting the solution that worked for me (successfully applying criteria as well as successfully querying against an EF data source):

```
    private Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetSearchExpression(string targetField, ExpressionType comparison, object value, string enumMethod)
    {
        return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)MakePredicate(DeQualifyFieldName(targetField, typeof(T)), comparison, value, enumMethod);
    }

    private LambdaExpression MakePredicate(string[] memberNames, ExpressionType comparison, object value, string enumMethod = "Any")
    {
        //create parameter for inner lambda expression
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
        Expression left = parameter;

        //Get the value against which the property/field will be compared
        var right = Expression.Constant(value);

        var currentType = typeof(T);
        for (int x = 0; x < memberNames.Count(); x++)
        {
            string memberName = memberNames[x];
            if (FieldExists(currentType, memberName))
            {
                //assign the current type member type 
                currentType = SingleLevelFieldType(currentType, memberName);
                left = Expression.PropertyOrField(left == null ? parameter : left, memberName);

                //mini-loop for non collection objects
                if (!currentType.IsGenericType || (!(currentType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>) ||
                                                     currentType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))))
                    continue;

                ///Begin loop for collection objects -- this section can only run once

                //get enum method
                if (enumMethod.Length < 2) throw new Exception("Invalid enum method target.");
                bool negateEnumMethod = enumMethod[0] == '!';
                string methodName = negateEnumMethod ? enumMethod.Substring(1) : enumMethod;

                //get the interface sub-type
                var itemType = currentType.GetInterfaces()
                                          .Single(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
                                          .GetGenericArguments()[0];

                //generate lambda for single item
                var itemPredicate = MakeSimplePredicate(itemType, memberNames[++x], comparison, value);

                //get method call
                var staticMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMember(methodName).OfType<MethodInfo>()
                                                     .Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                                                     .First()
                                                     .MakeGenericMethod(itemType);

                //generate method call, then break loop for return
                left = Expression.Call(null, staticMethod, left, itemPredicate);
                right = Expression.Constant(!negateEnumMethod);
                comparison = ExpressionType.Equal;
                break;
            }
        }

        //build the final expression
        var binaryExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(comparison, left, right);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(binaryExpression, parameter);
    }

    static LambdaExpression MakeSimplePredicate(Type inputType, string memberName, ExpressionType comparison, object value)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(inputType, "t");
        Expression left = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, memberName);
        return Expression.Lambda(Expression.MakeBinary(comparison, left, Expression.Constant(value)), parameter);
    }

    private static Type SingleLevelFieldType(Type baseType, string fieldName)
    {
        Type currentType = baseType;
        MemberInfo match = (MemberInfo)currentType.GetField(fieldName) ?? currentType.GetProperty(fieldName);
        if (match == null) return null;
        return GetFieldOrPropertyType(match);
    }

    public static Type GetFieldOrPropertyType(MemberInfo field)
    {
        return field.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property ? ((PropertyInfo)field).PropertyType : ((FieldInfo)field).FieldType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove qualifying names from a target field.  For example, if targetField is "Order.Customer.Name" and
    /// targetType is Order, the de-qualified expression will be "Customer.Name" split into constituent parts
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="targetField"></param>
    /// <param name="targetType"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string[] DeQualifyFieldName(string targetField, Type targetType)
    {
        return DeQualifyFieldName(targetField.Split('.'), targetType);
    }

    public static string[] DeQualifyFieldName(string[] targetFields, Type targetType)
    {
        var r = targetFields.ToList();
        foreach (var p in targetType.Name.Split('.'))
            if (r.First() == p) r.RemoveAt(0);
        return r.ToArray();
    }
```

I included related methods in case someone actually needs to sort through this at some point. :)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

My first attempt would be to identify if the instance is `Enumerable<T>` and treat the member name as method instead of a property/field like this

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> MakePredicate<T>(
        string memberPath, ExpressionType comparison, object value)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
        var right = Expression.Constant(value);
        var left = memberPath.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)param, (target, memberName) =>
        {
            if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(target.Type))
            {
                var enumerableType = target.Type.GetInterfaces()
                    .Single(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));
                return Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), memberName, enumerableType.GetGenericArguments(), target);
            }
            return Expression.PropertyOrField(target, memberName);
        });
        var body = Expression.MakeBinary(comparison, left, right);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
    }
}
```

and try use it as follows

```
var predicate = ExpressionUtils.MakePredicate<Order>(
    "StatusLogs.First.CreatedDate", ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual, new DateTime(2016, 1, 1));
```

The possible methods are `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Last`, `LastOrDefault`, `Singe` and `SingleOrDefault`.

But then you'll find that from the above methods only **`FirstOrDefault`** is supported in **EF** predicates.

Hence we can hardcode that call for collection types and do not include it in the accessors like this

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> MakePredicate2<T>(
        string memberPath, ExpressionType comparison, object value)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
        var right = Expression.Constant(value);
        var left = memberPath.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)param, (target, memberName) =>
        {
            if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(target.Type))
            {
                var enumerableType = target.Type.GetInterfaces()
                    .Single(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));
                target = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "FirstOrDefault", enumerableType.GetGenericArguments(), target);
            }
            return Expression.PropertyOrField(target, memberName);
        });
        var body = Expression.MakeBinary(comparison, left, right);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
    }
}
```

and use it as follows

```
var predicate = ExpressionUtils.MakePredicate<Order>(
    "StatusLogs.CreatedDate", ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual, new DateTime(2016, 1, 1));
```

**P.S.** While this will work, it might not produce the intended result. `IEnumerable<T>` navigation property means `one-to-many` relationship and assuming that the condition should apply only for the first (whatever that means in database, it's rather random) element does not make much sense. I would rather imply `Any` and try to build expression like this in the above case

```
t => t.StatusLogs.Any(s => s.CreatedDate >= new DateTime(2016, 1, 1))
```

or support `FirstOrDefault`, `Any`, `All`, (eventually `Count`, `Sum`, `Min`, `Max`) and handle them differently inside the builder.

Still IMO for collections `Any` is the most logical equivalent of the single entity criteria.

But all that will be another story (question).

**UPDATE:** Initially I was thinking to stop here, but for the sake of completeness, here is a sample implementation of the `Any` concept:

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> MakePredicate<T>(string memberPath, ExpressionType comparison, object value)
    {
        return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)MakePredicate(
            typeof(T), memberPath.Split('.'), 0, comparison, value);
    }

    static LambdaExpression MakePredicate(Type targetType, string[] memberNames, int index, ExpressionType comparison, object value)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(targetType, targetType.Name.ToCamel());
        Expression target = parameter;
        for (int i = index; i < memberNames.Length; i++)
        {
            if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(target.Type))
            {
                var itemType = target.Type.GetInterfaces()
                    .Single(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
                    .GetGenericArguments()[0];
                var itemPredicate = MakePredicate(itemType, memberNames, i, comparison, value);
                return Expression.Lambda(
                    Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { itemType }, target, itemPredicate),
                    parameter);
            }
            target = Expression.PropertyOrField(target, memberNames[i]);
        }
        if (value != null && value.GetType() != target.Type)
            value = Convert.ChangeType(value, target.Type);
        return Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.MakeBinary(comparison, target, Expression.Constant(value)),
            parameter);
    }

    static string ToCamel(this string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || char.IsLower(s[0])) return s;
        if (s.Length < 2) return s.ToLower();
        var chars = s.ToCharArray();
        chars[0] = char.ToLower(chars[0]);
        return new string(chars);
    }
}
```

so for this sample model

```
public class Foo
{
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public ICollection<Baz> Bazs { get; set; }
}

public class Baz
{
    public ICollection<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

the sample expression

```
var predicate = ExpressionUtils.MakePredicate<Foo>(
    "Bars.Bazs.Details.Amount", ExpressionType.GreaterThan, 1234);
```

produces

```
foo => foo.Bars.Any(bar => bar.Bazs.Any(baz => baz.Details.Any(detail => detail.Amount > 1234)))
```

Comment: A number of points you made look very promising. I'll have to wait for Monday to apply, but I'll be back to get you a green check mark ASAP. :)

Comment: Ivan, I've spent a number of hours with this today. A quick note: the line 'if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom...' does not compile; I changed it to 'IEnumerable<>'. There were a number of other challenges; in particular, the method call didn't work for me (similar to earlier errors).

I finally got it working, using clues from both you and Marc. It's not what I'd term a "general solution" yet, but I'll post as is.

Comment: @Daniel I've tested everything before posting and it's working (EF 6.1.3). The code `typeof(IEnumerable)` should be exactly as posted - I'm surprised you didn't realize that you need to include `using System.Collections` - VS should be suggesting that when you do Ctrl dot.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that you were completely right about IEnumerable. It was recognized under Collections.Generic as needing a type parameter, and it never clicked for me that this would be why. As funny as this sounds, I learned to add "using System.Collections.Generic;" before I know what generics really were, so I've always thought of it as sort of a "general collections" include.

I've made additional refinements to my solution and am feeling good, but I will come back to your answer when I can, if nothing else other than to learn.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey @IvanStoev do you know how to do a Contains of an enumerable? Like searching a number into an array using expressions.

Answer (score 1):

What you are possibly looking for is `System.Linq.Enumerable.First<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)` etc, so: start at `typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable)` and work from there. Note: you mention `IEnumerable<T>`, but it is *possible* that you *actually* mean `IQueryable<T>`, in which case you want `Queryable.First<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)` etc. Maybe this difference (between `Enumerable` and `Queryable`) is why EF "throws a fit".

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Marc! Unfortunately I've tried that--note that I was able to find the method by using typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod(). I tries using Queryable instead, which didn't fix the issue but may prevent a future issue.

The specific error EF gives is: "Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'MyType Last[MyType](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyType])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." I'm assuming it's because it's a static method, though I'm not sure.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @Daniel does it work when you do the same using LINQ syntax rather than reflection / Expression?